# input range html5 can't get value

Tags: css, html, slider

Maybe the title is not the best one but I exactly don't know how to ask this.

I am developing something and I need a really simple html range slider.

I can customize it perfectly so it is not a problem but, after test it a lot... It looks like:
- In phone and tablets works perfectly (just tested from the Chrome developer tools)
- Desktop (so, with mouse) it has a problem.

**The problem:**
The most of the times... it gets bugged. After click on it and move the cursor and then click again to fix my choice... it doesn't stop to be focused, so the cursor still moves... So it means I can't select one value. So, fucked and refresh.

And this slider is at the end of a huge form so, after create all if someone has to refresh... it is so bad.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96es9zrt/

This is my layout:

```
<input type="range" step="10" min="10" max="50" value="50">
```

It has no style except the custom css. BTW, I don'tknow why... in the fiddle the line disappears when the cursor is moving. It doesn't happen to me

```
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.78);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #46e5d2;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin-top: -11px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: rgba(214, 214, 214, 0.78);
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.78);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #46e5d2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: rgba(194, 194, 194, 0.78);
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.78);
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #46e5d2;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.78);
    outline: 0;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: rgba(214, 214, 214, 0.78);
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

watch out! You've set the slider's height to 0px! It makes so that when you use it, the bar will disappear! Just set it to something else

```css
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;  //change this!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
    background: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.78);
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

As you can see here, now it works properly https://jsfiddle.net/96es9zrt/1/